# add NULL in foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know it is possible to allow `NULL` in foreign key but I'm having a hard time looking for an answer. I'm using postgresql and the command "`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name INT NULL`" did not work. I used this so that my foreign key will allow `NULL` in it. How to do it right in postgresql?

Here's my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE table1."authorization"
(
  authorization_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table1.authorization_seq'::regclass),
  process_id integer,
  site_id integer,
  parent_opted_out boolean,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorization_id ),
  CONSTRAINT table2_fk FOREIGN KEY (process_id)
      REFERENCES table2.process (process_id) MATCH Unknown
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"? Did you get an error message? Can you share it please?

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes.

Comment: can you show us your table defination where u defining foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. To remove the `not null` modifier from a column, you should use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name DROP NOT NULL
```

Comment: This way can I save "NULL" values even if it is a foreign key? thanks!

Comment: @asdasdas I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: my foreign key is "process_id" and it does not accepts NULL values. So if I executed this, "ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN process_id DROP NOT NULL", will I be able to save "NULL" values? thanks

Comment: @asdasdas yes, it will.